Android Compose Crossfade screen movement
"sectionState.value = POST_ROUTE" Why does this code not work storage?
Crossfade(
    modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding),
    targetState = sectionState.value
) { section ->
    when (section) {
        POST_ROUTE -> PostScreen(
            userData = userData
        )
        VIDEO_ROUTE -> VideoScreen()
        IMAGE_ROUTE -> ImageScreen()
        MY_INFO_ROUTE -> MyInfoScreen()
        ADD_POST_ROUTE -> AddPostScreen(userData = userData) {
            // Back button on topbar
            sectionState.value = POST_ROUTE
        }
    }
}

